# BeautifulSoup doesn't find elements

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I started to use BeautifulSoup and unfortunately it doesn't work as expected.

In the following link https://www.globes.co.il/news/article.aspx?did=1001285059 includes the following element:

```
<div class="sppre_message-data-wrapper">... </div>
```

I tried to get this element by writing the following code:

```
html = urlopen("https://www.globes.co.il/news/article.aspx?did=1001285059")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), features="html.parser")
comments = bsObj.find_all('div', {'class': ["sppre_message-data-wrapper"]})
print(comments)
```

'comments' gave an empty array

Comment: whats your expected output?

Comment: That's strange.. I didn't find that element in the link you provided.

Comment: @Xosrov : Yes you are right.Not even me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in an iframe. Make your request to the iframe src

```
https://spoxy-shard2.spot.im/v2/spot/sp_8BE2orzs/post/1001285059/?elementId=6a97624752c75d958352037d2b36df77&spot_im_platform=desktop&host_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.globes.co.il%2Fnews%2Farticle.aspx%3Fdid%3D1001285059&host_url_64=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ2xvYmVzLmNvLmlsL25ld3MvYXJ0aWNsZS5hc3B4P2RpZD0xMDAxMjg1MDU5&pageSize=1&count=1&spot_im_ph__prerender_deferred=true&prerenderDeferred=true&sort_by=newest&conversationSkin=light&isStarsRatingEnabled=false&enableMessageShare=true&enableAnonymize=true&isConversationLiveBlog=false&enableSeeMoreButton=true
```

py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://spoxy-shard2.spot.im/v2/spot/sp_8BE2orzs/post/1001285059/?elementId=6a97624752c75d958352037d2b36df77&spot_im_platform=desktop&host_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.globes.co.il%2Fnews%2Farticle.aspx%3Fdid%3D1001285059&host_url_64=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ2xvYmVzLmNvLmlsL25ld3MvYXJ0aWNsZS5hc3B4P2RpZD0xMDAxMjg1MDU5&pageSize=1&count=1&spot_im_ph__prerender_deferred=true&prerenderDeferred=true&sort_by=newest&conversationSkin=light&isStarsRatingEnabled=false&enableMessageShare=true&enableAnonymize=true&isConversationLiveBlog=false&enableSeeMoreButton=true')
soup= bs(r.content,'html.parser')
comments = [item.text for item in soup.select('.sppre_message-data-wrapper')]
print(comments)
```

BeautifulSoup doesn't support deep combinator (which is now retired I think anyway) but you can see this in browser (Chrome) using:

```
*/deep/.sppre_message-data-wrapper
```

Wouldn't have mattered ultimately as content is not present in requests response from original url.

You could alternatively use selenium I guess and switch to iframe. Whilst there is an id of `401bccf8039377de3e9873905037a855-iframe` i.e. #401bccf8039377de3e9873905037a855-iframe  for find_element_by_css_selector, to then switch to, a more robust (in case id is dynamic) selector would be `.sppre_frame-container iframe`

Comment: Can you please explain how you went about identifying this particular iframe as the source of the comments? I tried to replicate it, but it only worked with a trial-and-error approach...

Comment: The OP had found that html on the page (at least we start with that assertion) - a simple class selector didn't return results. The next thought is that therefore it may be in an iframe. I used the deep combinator syntax I show above to search through iframes as well (in the browser). The match returned gave me the right iframe to use.

Comment: It's deprecated though there is another syntax version around